# Creating a grid of ggplot graphs from a list using gridExtra

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I'm trying to create an automated graphing function and have a few questions about laying out graphs from lists in `ggplot2` using `grid.arrange`

Here's toy data

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(rep(NA,20))
for (i in 1:6) df[,i] <- rnorm(20, 0, 3)
names(df) <- paste("a", 1:6, sep = "")
```

Now create a simple graphing function with a contingency based on presence or absence of an argument, in this case whether or not a note is added to the graph (*note: I am doing it this way to represent my real workflow as closely as possible*)

```
gFunct <- function (vec, note = NULL) {
  if(is.null(note)) {
  g <- ggplot(df, aes_string(vec)) + geom_histogram()
  return(g)
  } else {
  g <- ggplot(df, aes_string(vec)) + geom_histogram() + annotate("text", x = 0, y = 3, label = note)
  return(g)
  }
}
```

Now create two lists

```
nameList <- names(df)
noteList <- list(a1 = NULL, a2 = "hey", a3 = "hey there", a4 = NULL, a5 = NULL, a6 = "there")
```

Now pass those lists into the graphing function via the `foreach` function

```
library(foreach)
gg <- foreach(x = nameList, y = noteList) %do% gFunct(x,y)
```

What we get when we call `gg` is a list of graphs, indexed by `[[idx]]`. I want to know two things

(1) How to pass these into `grid.arrange` without needing to turn them into grobs in the graphing function. At the moment I'm getting an error message saying `only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"`but on other occasions I have not needed to convert `ggplot2` graphs to grobs to pass them into `grid.arrange`.

(2) Leaving aside the grob problem, is there any way to pass the whole list into `grid.arrange` without having to list every graph manually? In other words I would like to be able to create the matrix of graphs with

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(gg, ncol = 3)
```

rather than

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(gg[[1]], gg[[2]], gg[[3]], gg[[4]], gg[[5]], gg[[6]], ncol = 3)
```

Comment: Not sure it's what you are looking for, but have you tried `marrangeGrob(gg, ncol = 3, nrow = 2)`?

Comment: `marrangeGrob` is for multipage arrangements. If you want the plots all on a single page, then use `grid.arrange`. To pass a list of plot objects to either function, use the `grobs` argument: `grid.arrange(grobs=gg, ncol=3)`.

Comment: I've found `cowplot::plot_grid()` to be more consistent with plot formatting. `gridExtra::grid.arrange()` presented some issues with title and legend formatting, both lost their proportions relative to main plot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = gg, ncol = 3)
```